# Netgear WGR614L Wireless G Router - access configuration

Tags: router

I reset the wireless router with a toothpick. I was hoping that I could access the router settings, by default settings. Apparently userid/password = admin/password does not work. Are there other measures I can take?

Answer (score 1):

make sure yo fully reset, some of the time it takes holding the reset for 30+ seconds depending on model/make.

Answer (score 0):

Ttry this::

```
Username:"root" 

Password:"admin"
```

without quotes

Reference about Router installation
http://www.myopenrouter.com/article/10339/DD-WRT-for-NETGEAR-WGR614L-Installation-Guide/

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you have not reset it correctly then, with the router plugged in and powered on get your toothpick and hold it into the reset hole till the lights on the front of the router flash. you will then be able to access it on http://192.168.0.1 and use the admin/password credentials.

There is of course another possibility that your router is issued by an ISP that hard codes the login credentials in which case see the tag on the bottom of the router which will tell you the default username and password